# How to remove search box and pagination from print page in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Jquery data table in codeigniter and now i want to Print web page but i want to remove search box and pagination
during printing webpage. How can i do this? Here is my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data)
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="PrintElem('#yourdiv')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media print
{
.noprint {display:none;}
}
```

Add class `noprint` to your search box and pagination.